# How to set particular default value in INPUT TEXT field in JSP

Tags: jsp

I want to set default value in my Text box on JSP and when editied, the new value should get stored.

For Ex:

Suppose i have a Text box with Label name as "No Of Days", so on page load 360 should come in the text box. When user edit this to supoose to 250 then 250 should got saved and when user comes again to that same page then 250 should come in the box and if user do not enter anythin then 360 should come.

Someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to set default value in my Text box on JSP and when edited, the new value should get stored.

You can use JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function()
 {
   document.getElementById("noOfDays").value = 360; //assuming input text id is "noOfDays"
 };
</script>
```

On every page load text field always has value 360 by default unless user enters any new value.

> When user edit this to suppose to 250 then 250 should got saved?

**Where?** To database?

With above JavaScript code you can edit the textfield value to 250, but you need to save some where such as database because value 250 will be get flushed when page is reloaded, again you will see 360.

You can submit the form to one servlet that servlet will save the value entered by the user. In this case you do not need to use above JavaScript code. You can fetch the saved value from servlet , if value is not present then you can set to default value 360 and display on to JSP.

Please include some code what have you tried for further help.

#### Useful links

- [jsp example tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/2021/jsp-example-tutorial-for-beginners)
- [coreservlets tutorial](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use Logic Present and Logic Notpresent tag.
Put Default value in Logic Notpresent tag and in Logic Present tag put the line code which gets stored value from database.

For Example:

```
<logic:notPresent name="name1">
<html:text property="propertyName"  styleClass="text" styleId="propertyId" value="defaultValue" ></html:text>

</logic:notPresent>
<logic:present name="name1">
<html:text property="propertyName" styleClass="text" styleId="propertyId" value="${requestScope.var[0].noOfDays}" ></html:text>
</logic:present>
```

Here, `noOfDays` is used as an example. Put variable name you declared.